# PHP: extract numbers between two strings using regex

Tags: php, regex, string, numbers, extract

I have a string which can take 3 forms (or two if you want):

- Showing **3** Results
- Showing 1 - 12 of **79** Results
- Showing 1 - 12 of **2,513** Results

And what I want is to get the numbers in bold (without comma)...

I can do that using many string functions and conditions, but I'm pretty sure there's an easy and elegant way to do so using regular expressions... which aren't, unfortunately, my strong point.

Comment: You just want the number right before `Results`?

Comment: Why downvoting people ? this website exists to answer such n00b questions !! :-/

Comment: Actually, the goal of the website is to help noobs fix their programs. You're supposed to do some initial study some attempt to solve the problem yourself, show what you tried, and then we can show you where you went wrong. You learn by making and correcting mistakes, not by having solutions spoon-fed to you.

Comment: @Barmar, I agree now the question was stupid since that was easy... I'm improving now with practice, but at the time I really had no clue how to achieve it, I googled for hours without succes... So I still think these downvotes are mean :<

Comment: If noobs came by here, here's another way to do it =) : http://regex101.com/r/vE1xC4

Comment: That only works if there's at most one comma in the number. You can add more repetitions, but can't handle an arbitrary number.

Comment: I just wanted to avoid a second line to replace the commas... and here's we back to your solution =D  ... http://regex101.com/r/dZ9yN4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
preg_match('/([0-9,]+) Results/', $string, $match);
$number = str_replace(',', '', $match[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$number = preg_replace('/^.*([\d,]+) Results$/', '$1', $original);
$number = preg_relpace('/,/', '', $number);
```

Comment: Surely using a regex to remove commas is overkill, no?

Comment: @jim, correct the second `preg_re*lpace`... but still doesnt work... For example it gives as a result: `Showing 1 - 12 of 2513 Results`